# Delphi and Indy 10 configuration for Zoopla RTDF

Tags: delphi, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, indy

I'm using Delphi XE5 and Indy 10 components to update Rightmove and Zoopla for an estate agent.  The program is to run on a Windows 2012R2 server.

Rightmove supply a client certificate, public key file with keystore password and a root certificate.  I have their system all set up working perfectly with TLS v1.2.

Zoopla, however, work differently.  They ask you to create a CSR using OpenSSL, keep the private key generated and send them the CSR. They then send you back a certificate and say the whole system is self-cert.  No root certificate.

I am trying to connect using TLS v1.2 and getting an error message from Indy (possibly from OpenSSL via Indy) that includes the phrase:

> "SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

Here's what their tech guy sent me:

> The wat the relationship is setup up is that You install/configure both the private.pem key file (the private key) and the certificate.crt file (the public key signed by the rootCA, which is ZPG) on your server. Depends what server you have where you put the files but they are normally called ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key (thats the nginx directives) or something like that for apache.
>   the rootCA certificate which you are referring to is installed here at ZPG and isn't intended to be distributed.  in a lot of literature the relation ship is actually inverted.
>   zpg:  Acts as both the CA And the 'browser' / 'client'
>   your server: act as the webhost/server in this instance

Anybody understand what this guy is saying and know how I configure Indy to work this way?

All help in this will be greatly appreciated and I'll be happy to supply any further info that you feel would help.

EDIT:

The following works from Windows command prompt using cURL:

> echo { "branch_reference" : "test" } |
>   curl --key zoopla.key --cert zoopla.crt --data @-
>   --header "Content-type: application/json;
>   profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.1/schemas/listing/list.json"
>   https://realtime-listings-api.webservices.zpg.co.uk/sandbox/v1/listing/list

How do I do this using Indy?